# How to view table structure using plugin in tinyMCE?

Tags: php, html-table, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE version 3.5.5 and I need to insert tables into it.

I have gone through the '[table plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:table)' documentation and I got success in adding tables into the editor also.

But, after creating table, if source is viewed it shows just string typed in but no `<td><tr>` or other tags related to table.

If saved on same condition, only strings typed are getting stored into database.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I got it finally with partial success.

```
valid_elements : "-strong/-b[class|style],-u[class|style],#p[id|style|dir|class|align],-ol[class|style],-ul[class|style],-li[class|style],br,-strike[class|style],+a[id|rev|href|lang|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|style],-blockquote[dir|style],-font[face|size|style|id|class|dir|color],-span[style|class|align]"
```

If I keep any tags in `valid_elements` string, it is not showing any table structure. If i remove it, it is working. Please let me know where exactly issue is?

Thanks